# ターミナルごとにシェルの使い分けは可能か？

Tags: shellscript

こんにちは。コンピュータを独学している学生（Mac）です。ターミナルをかっこよくしたいという安易な考えから調べに調べてdefaultのbashからfishを使っていました。

しかし、anacondaにおけるcondaのインポートエラーがどうしても治らず
bashに戻しました。その時点ではiterm2を使用していました。

そして現在はterminalでbashを使用中です。
しかしfishの方が個人的に使いやすいです。なので

シェルを使い分けたいと考えています。以下例

- Terminal(Bash)
- iTerm2(fish)

これは可能でしょうか？また、可能であれば方法を教えて欲しいです。

Answer (score 3):

iTerm2のメニューの`Preferences`->`Profile`の現在選択されてるプロファイルで`Command`の指定ができますので、そこで`/usr/local/bin/fish`など`fish`のパスを入力すればログインシェルの代わりに任意のシェルを使えます。

Comment: この方法だとterminalを開いたときはbashでitermを開いた時はfishのように使い分けられますか？以前、fishを設定した時はどちらもfishになってしまったので、、